# Totalling Calculated fields with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have the following AngularJS code and I want to be able to total the calculated fields that appear in the results1 and results2 disabled inputs. Can someone advise how this is done?

Thanks,

John

```
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>
<body>

<form name="form" action="index.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">

<input type="text" name="field1" ng-model="field1" ng-init="field1='10'">

<input type="text" name="field2" ng-model="field2" ng-init="field2='10'">

<br>

<input type="text" name="results1" value="{{(+field1*100|currency)}}" disabled>

<input type="text" name="results2" value="{{(+field2*100|currency)}}" disabled>

</form>

<h1>{{(+results1--results2|currency:"")}}</h1>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `{{(+field1*100)-(-field2*100)|currency:"")}}` you need to use the model not the name of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <h1>{{(+field1--field2|currency:"")}}</h1>
 <h1>{{(+field1*100--field2*100|currency:"")}}</h1>
```

Can you try like this ?

Comment: Thats adds up the value of 10 and 10 in the fields. I want it to total up the calculated fields that are displayed in results1 and results2

Comment: then you can use like this.
     <h1>{{(+field1*100--field2*100|currency:"")}}</h1>

You can not get value by name in AngularJS.

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-value` instead of `value` to get that expression evaluated properly

Comment: I changed value to ng-value in results1 and2 and it then did not display the calculated fields.